# Call WF4 Worfklow Service with JQuery

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

How to call a WF4 workflow service using JQuery with Json serialization?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly. WF4 services only work with XML SOAP style services so you would need to convert the original JSON REST request to an XML SOAP request.